# Speed of copying files on a remote server

Tags: windows

Am I correct in saying that all the native Windows copy functions (i.e. command line & GUI) carry out a copy from one folder to another folder on the same remote server by reading the data across the WAN and then writing it back. As such, the copy speed is defined by the WAN speed.

Are there any utilities that can be used to somehow cause the copy to be carried out on the remote server without going across the WAN?

I have a very dim memory of NCOPY in Netware doing something like this, i.e. the copy was carried out by the server.

Does anything similar exist for Windows?

Comment: Nothing similar exists for windows in the same spirit as that. All solutions, as Jim and commentors below say, are variations on logging into the server itself to perform the copy.

Comment: ncopy is the same solution as using the WMI call.  Ncopy used a netware function call on the server to perform the copy.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways to have the copy process run on the remote server:

1. remote desktop to the server
2. use a WMI call to copy the files (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176985.aspx#EFAA)
3. use powershell remoting to invoke-command then copy-item (invoke-command syntax here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347578.aspx)
4. use schtasks to create a task on the remote system to run your copy command locally (http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Also using [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/bb897553) to remotely execute a copy command would be a scriptable option.